# Theoretical Machine Learning: How to get the Lipschitz constant and strong convexity constant from strict convex problems to calculate hyperparameters

Tags: convex-analysis, machine-learning

I am getting my head around convexity theory for machine learning and am looking into finding the right hyperparameter for a parametrized regression model/deep learning model. I know that you can calculate the hyperparameters through theory, it can tell us how to set hyperparameters for strongly convex optimization, which is defined like this,

**Strong Convexity** - a function $f$ is $\alpha$-strongly convex if $$ \nabla^2 f(x) \succeq \alpha I $$ for all $x$, where $I$ is the identity matrix, if we know the strong convexity constant µ and the Lipschitz constant L.

How to get the Lipschitz constant and strong convexity constant from strict convex problems to calculate hyperparameters in this case? Is it even useful to calcualte the hyperparameters through theory or is it normally done experimentally by using some convex loss function like least-square?

Comment: If you are thinking in deep learning as multiple layers of neurons (perceptron, convolutional, etc...), the short answer is that these type of models almost never lead to globally convex loss functions. The complexity of the loss function landscapes makes it very intractable to obtain convexity or Lipschitz constants even locally. There are some "tricks" you can do, but most of the time you experimentally tune the hyper-parameters. To the best of my knowledge there is still a big gap between theory and practice: the class of problems those theoretical papers can solve is very narrow.

Comment: Anyway, I was just answering the last question: "Is it even useful to calcualte the hyperparameters through theory or is it normally done experimentally by using some convex loss function like least-square?".